# Extract specific folder from a tar.gz

Tags: tar, gzip

I know this question was previously asked on this site before like here [1](https://superuser.com/questions/155838/how-to-extract-a-single-folder-and-its-subfolders-from-a-tarball-tar-gz) and here [2](https://superuser.com/questions/344950/how-can-i-extract-only-some-specific-folders-from-a-tar-gz-archive) but no success for me.

I want to extract the `Measures` folder from my S012011_csv.tar.gz zipped file. If I do `tar -ztvf file.tar.gz` to see the content, you can see the folder directory structure:

`global//scratch//chamar//data//S012011_csv/Measures/file1.csv`

`global//scratch//chamar//data//S012011_csv/Measures/file2.csv`

and so on (yes there are `//` and may be the real issue here).

I only want to extract the subfolder `Measures` under folder `S012011_csv` in the current directory of the `.tar.gz` folder.

I have tried all these options but no success:

```
tar -xvzf S012011-v41_csv.tar.gz --strip=6 ./global//scratch//chamar//book//S012011-v41_csv/Mearsures/*

tar -xvzf S012011-v41_csv.tar.gz --strip=6 global//scratch//chamar//book//S012011-v41_csv/Mearsures/*

tar -xvzf S012011-v41_csv.tar.gz --strip=6 global/scratch/chamar/book/S012011-v41_csv/Mearsures/*

tar -xvzf S012011-v41_csv.tar.gz global/scratch/chamar/book/S012011-v41_csv/Mearsures/*
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I've [asked](https://superuser.com/questions/746750/extract-specific-folder-from-a-tar-gz) this question on SuperUser.com but I think this site is more appropriate)

Comment: Good that you mentioned you had cross posted :) I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you try with `--strip=10` and include the double slashes in the directory name? I, too, think this is your main issue here. If this works, I think the last solution should work, too, if you add the double slashes where appropriate.

Comment: I am interested to know how these double slashes came to be in the file. Was this made with normal 'tar', or programmatically in some way? What happens when you extract *everything*? Does that work or does `tar` error on creating an empty directory?

Comment: @JosephR. thanks for the suggestion ... I tried and it didn't work. I have to restart my data processing job and zip the files properly.

Comment: @Anthon, the `//` comes from my Python tar zip code. Python requires `//` when you input the filepath but since I was sending an `os` linecode to Unix via Python, I think I don't need the `//`

Comment: Python should not need the `//`, you only need to escape a `\` (i.e.`\\`) as the backward slash introduces escape sequences. Alternatively you can use `r"\some\path"` for that, if you don't need other escapes for special characters.